# Handling Oracle Date type with Doctrine DBAL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, doctrine-orm, dbal

I have an already existing an working Oracle SQL that compares two dates:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE startDate <= TO_DATE(:startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD');

$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', 20160108);
```

As I said, this works fine.

I am trying to generate this query (or one that has the same results) with Doctrine's Query Builder, but I can't get it to work. This is what I did so far:

```
$startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Ymd', 20160108);

$queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('*');
$queryBuilder->from('table1');
$queryBuilder->where('startDate <= ' . $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($startDate, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME));
```

The above produces this output:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE startDate <= :dcValue1;
(:dcValue = '2016-01-08 00:00:00')
```

And Oracle complains with ORA-01861.

On an SQLite platform, this works fine. Any idea on how to this properly so that it works on both platforms?

Answer (score 1):

when casting a character string to date it must match the NLS date format, or be explicitely formatted. If your code must run on a DB where you cannot be sure what the default session format for dates will be, be explicit. As a general rule, I'd say always be explicit!

SELECT * from table1 where start_Date <= TO_DATE(:dcValue1,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');

Within your query builder, try something like this, although you will need to escape the single quotes in the format mask. I believe in DBAL that is done by doubling up the quote, but you will need to verify that :

```
$queryBuilder = $connection->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('*');
$queryBuilder->from('table1');
$queryBuilder->where('startDate <= TO_DATE(' . $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($startDate, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::DATETIME) . ' ,''yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'')');
```

Comment: The Oracle query works fine. I'm trying to figure out how to generate it from Doctrine's Query Builder.

Comment: Added something that may point you in the right direction. I'm not, however, all that familliar with DBAL so play with it and see where it gets you

Comment: You still didn't get it. TO_DATE is an Oracle specific function. If I write that in the Query Builder it will fail on any platform other than Oracle. I need to replace that with something that is compatible on all platforms.

Comment: Then you need to ensure that you have exact matching date formats between your systems. Talk to your DBA about that. If you are looking for a "standard" format that works everywhere - it doesn't exist in Oracle.

Comment: Now, if at connect time you know you are connecting to Oracle and can set the session date format using alter session set  nls_date_format="yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss", then that might work.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party,

I am assuming `$startDate` is a valid Date Object.

```
$startDate = $startDate->format('d-M-y h:i:s');
$queryBuilder->where('startDate <= ' . $startDate);
```

Hope this helps some one.

Thanks.